# parsing CSV file in java when delimiter is a part of data

Tags: java, csv, guava, opencsv

I am writing a CSV parts.Its easy to write it using java

```
String s = null
while( (s= bufferedReadr.readLine() !=null){
  String parts[] = s.split(',');
  //process parts
}

The problem is data is in format
"a", "b","c","d","e","f".

But some of the data is
"a" ,",b" ,"c",",a","e","f" .
```

EDIT

The thing is i get one line of CSV input from some other code which i cant change.

SO i get each line which is in CSV format. And i want to split that.I cant use  csvlibs as they parse whole file and requie a handle to file.

some quote are present withing data parts which is causing problem.

How do i resolve this?Any open src libs i can use?

Comment: `opencsv`, Super CSV. Is your Google down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not split data yourself. Use one of available libraries that do this job well. For example take a look on [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: :Can you comment on my latets edit

Comment: @user93796, no problem. Check the API. It should allow passing stream or reader. You can always wrap string using `StringReader` and use CSV parser with single line. If you however want to work hard and pare it yourself you can play with positive/nagative lookahead `(?!X)`, but it seems to be complicated. I personally do not know how to write such regex. Alternatively you can split string yourself by iterating on characters and calling `substring()`. This will work.

Comment: I used apache commons CSVReader finally.

Comment: @user93796, CSVReader is a good choice. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As the other comments say, use OpenCSV.
There is the CSVReadr class with this contructor

```
public CSVReader(Reader reader, char separator, char quotechar)
```

And methods like `readAll(), readNext(), ....`
About the Reader, there are many different options:`.., InputStreamReader, StringReader`